# Why sorting Edges of a graph takes O(E log E) time?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, runtime, big-o

I am trying to calculate the runtime of the Minimum Spanning Tree algorithm.

Here is the algorithm: 
[image]

I understand tuntimes of steps from 1 to 3. But I really dont understand why it takes O(E logE) time to sort edges in non decreasing order.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because most powerful algorithms (mergesort, heapsort, quicksort) guarantee to sort a collection of n items in n log n worst case time. See prove [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort). In your case E seems to be the number of edges. So E log E to sort them all.

Answer (score 2):

All comparison-based sorting algorithms take at least $\Omega(n \log n)$ time to sort $n$ numbers, and heapsort and mergesort are asymptotically optimal in that they take $O(n \log n)$ time.

Answer (score 1):

Step 4 sorts all *|E|* edges in the graph.

Assume we use quicksort or an equivalent algorithm, so that step will use *O(n log n)* time to perform the step. In this case, *n = |E|*, so the sorting step requires *O(|E| log |E|)*.

Answer (score 1):

All generic comparison sorts cannot perform better than O(n log n) in the average or worst case. So the author picked the average scenario for any sorting algorithm, which you can choose by yourself.